# Add grid boxes dynamically using angular flex layout

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I'm new to angular flexLayout and not sure how to dynamically align boxes horizontally using flex layout.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Here is how I expected

[image]

But this is what I'm getting
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5bf7q3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

[image]

Comment: you didn't import FlexLayoutModule, in module definition, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wp8oks

Comment: updated https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5bf7q3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: this see, aligned in row https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wp8oks?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I wanted the first yellow block to be spread from start to end and the purple blocks below the yellow block to be in a row

Comment: follow https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/responsive